# LIKE Condition in PHP Not Work correctly

Tags: php, database, get, conditional-statements, sql-like

i have a row in my database with name "active_sizes" and i want filter my website items by size, for this, i use LIKE Condition in php :

```
AND active_sizes LIKE '%" . $_GET['size'] . "%'
```

but by using this code i have problem

for example when `$_GET['size']=7.0` this code shows items that `active_sizes=17.0`

my active_sizes value looks like `17.0,5.0,6.5,7.5,,`

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using comma-separated values in a single field in a database is indicative of bad design. You should normalize things, and have a seperate "item_sizes" table. As it stands now, you need a VERY ugly where clause to handle such sub-string mismatches:

```
$s = (intval)$_GET['size'];

... WHERE (active_sizes = $s)   // the only value in the field
      OR (active_sizes LIKE '$s%,') // at the beginning of the field
      OR (active_sizes LIKE '%,$s,%')  // in the middle of the field
      OR (active_sizes LIKE '%,$s') // at the end of the field
```

Or, if you normalized things properly and had these individual values in their own child table:

```
WHERE (active_sizes_child.size = $s)
```

I know which one I'd choose to go with...

You don't state which DB you're using, but if you're in MySQL, you can temporarily accomplish the same thing with

```
WHERE find_in_set($s, active_sizes)
```

at the cost of losing portability. Relevant docs here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: i use WHERE find_in_set($s, active_sizes)

Answer (score 0):

You Have `%` signs around your `$_GET` value. Combined with `LIKE`, this means that any string that simply contains your get value will be retuned. If you want an exact match, use the `=` operator instead, without the percentage signs.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your immediate issue:

```
AND active_sizes LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['size']) . "%'
```

If you are using the database other than MySQL, use corresponding escape function. Never trust input data.

Besides, I'd suggest using numeric field ([DECIMAL or NUMERIC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html)) for `active_sizes` field. This will accelerate your queries, will let you consume less memory, create queries like `active_sizes BETWEEN 16.5 AND 17.5`, and generally this is more correct data type for a shoe size.